# Connecting to a Virtual Machine(Hyper-v windows 11) from outside the Network with Remote Desktop controll. have i done everything till now right?

Tags: virtual-machine, remote-desktop, hyper-v, port

thats another Post, almost the same Question, but this time i am almost done , and i want to ask if i did everything right up to this point.

So what i want to archieve?

I want to reach the my Virtual machine, which i created in Hyper-v, that is on my local Pc with remot-desktop-controll. But Not locally rather from Outside of the Local Network.

First i did create  on the Ethernet Client a Static IP-Adress, i hope that created the STatic IP-Adress on the right (Client?)

Then i went on My router Settings to do make a Portforwarding Entry. The Port is 3389. So i added the Port on the first and Third casket(hopefully this is right) and i also did select my Computer, so the Router knows on which device the Port is running.

So If everything till now is correct, i should be able to connect my Virtual Machine from outside the Local network, but the most important thing is security. How i can encrypt the Port Connection and how can i encrypt the Remote Desktop connection?

[image: Local Computer and virtual machine]

[image: The Network Client(I dont know if you call it that way, on which i created the static IP-Adress]

[image]

[image: Adding the Remote-Desktop Port on My Router Settings, hopefully i wrote the Port in the correct Chaskets]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the most important thing is security. How i can encrypt the Port
> Connection and how can i encrypt the Remote Desktop connection?

If you wish to encrypt the connection, you need to use a VPN or SSH connection instead of Port Forwarding.

So far as I know, Port Fowarding is not a secure encrypted connection.

[SSH to encrypt port forwarding](https://www.concordia.ca/ginacody/aits/support/faq/ssh-tunnel.html#:%7E:text=SSH%20tunneling%2C%20or%20SSH%20port,machine%20via%20a%20secure%20channel.)

> Example:
>
> How do I create an SSH Tunnel to the ENCS Matlab License Servers
> (Windows)? Before beginning the procedure below you will need to
> install an SSH client such as PuTTy
>
> Launch PuTTy  In the Category pane of the PuTTY Configuration window,
> expand Connection then expand SSH and select Tunnels. Under "Options
> controlling SSH port forwarding" enter the following: Source Port:
> 1711 Destination: license-matlab.encs.concordia.ca:1711 Click the Add
> button Add another source port and destination Source port: 5001
> Destination: license-matlab.encs.concordia.ca:5001 Click the Add
> button In the Category pane of the PuTTY Configuration window, click
> on Session Under "Basic options for your PuTTy session" enter:
> Hostname: tunnel.encs.concordia.ca Port: 22 Saved Sessions: Matlab
> Click Save Click Open  If you have not set up authorized_keys, then
> you will be prompted for your ENCS password in order to establish the
> tunnel. Do not close the PuTTy window. Note: Everytime you wish to use
> Matlab on your PC, this SSH tunnel has to established with the Matlab
> License Servers prior to the application being launched.

======

You have another open question on this same subject that you should follow up on.

Comment: okey my bad for posting a complete new question. Thank you for the explanation about ssh. but you havent anwsered my first question? have i done everything up to this point right, based of the Ethernet Configuration and creating a forwarding port?

Comment: So far it seems to be correct with (a) setting up static IP - covered in the other question and (b) basic port forwarding.

Comment: Okey thank you. In google i am finding articles saying, that i can secure my Portforwarding with VPNs. And another point, i am not using port forwarding to secure my connection, i am using port forwarding to create a connection to outside network

Comment: You can use VPN or SSH to secure the connection.  Port Forwarding is a way to connect, yes.  But securing the connection requires VPN or SSH

Comment: ah okey. I am impressed about your knowledge, for me it seems like i will never reach this point where i have a answer for everything like you, and i also want to thank you for every answer that you wrote for me. You are helping me since the first thread and i couldnt even say Thank you!

Comment: You can Up Vote answers you find helpful.

Comment: cant do that, because my Reputation is under 15 if i understood it correct.

Comment: You CAN mark the Answer as a Correct Answer (everyone at whatever Rep can do that) if this works for you. I have upvoted your question so your rep should be good now. Your rep is 21.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133567/discussion-between-kongiponki-kongiponki-and-john).

Comment: i was about to install Putty but the question is where should i install it? On the Virtual Machine or the Local Computer, which you can see on the first Image? It would be acutally pretty nice, if i connect from outside, that i only connect to the virtual Machine and not to the host computer. The Portforwarding i did in the Local Host Computer that was okey i guess, but not sure where to install the Putty Software

Comment: Putty software is pretty much terminal software. It can go on any machine. Probably one place is the remote machine you are coming from. There other place might be the Host machine holding the VM. Once installed, your can use ti to connect to any other machine..   I put the same answer in Chat.

Comment: okey. Some people said, i shouldnt add the Remote Desktop Port 3389  in the Router Configuration  because as soon as you open this connection, People can try to break through and hack you. So i should turn the Port forwarding off as long as i havent Configurated Putty. But the Question is. When i have configurated Putty and started it, how can i be sure, that the Remote Desktop Connection is encrypted? And do i need to Start the Putty Software every time i start my Computer?

Comment: I don't think Putty can tell you if RDP is encrypted. This circles back to needing a VPN (or SSH tunnel).

Comment: Putty can connect to an SSH Tunnel and looks here (my Putty) that it can make one as well. But you would have to read up on that. There are a number of Putty options. ... Protocol Options, Sharing Connections.